# Send an email through Salesforce server from External Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, email, salesforce

I have an angular application, and wants to send an email to Salesforce contacts from external application through salesforce server.

I did not find any api or javascript file which allows me to write the code to send an email through salesforce server from external application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sendEmail()](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm) to send one or more emails via Salesforce. It can be either a [SingleEmailMessage](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm#SingleEmailMessage) or a [MassEmailMessage](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm#MassEmailMessage).

MassEmailMessage is more useful if you are dealing with a collection of Contacts, Leads or Users. See [What's the Advantage of using MassEmailMessage instead of multiple SingleEmailMessage?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/5169/102)

Comment: How can I use send email classes and its function in my angular class ? Is any api or js library requires to add in angular application ?

Comment: Is there any API which I can call from my nodeserver?

Comment: The native API exposed by Salesforce for sending emails is SOAP based. So you will need to figure out the best way to call it from your environment. You may find it easier to create your own REST based API in Apex. See [Is it possible to send an email via the REST API?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/17345/102)